# Evitar 'Memory Exhausted' al traer una cantidad elevada de registros sin aumentar php.ini@memory_limit

Tags: php, eloquent

Quiero traerme una cantidad elevada de registros usando el ORM Eloquent. Este es el error que me sale.

```
Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 20480 bytes) in illuminate/database/Eloquent/Concerns/HasAttributes.php on line 121
```

La consulta por si quereis verla es:

```
$center = CenterModel::where('id', $AnnotationsData['id'])->select('NumberOfDaysAnnotationList')->first()->toArray();

        $dateObject = new \DateTime('now');
        $dateNowSubXDays = $dateObject->sub( new \DateInterval('P'.$center['NumberOfDaysAnnotationList'].'D') )->format('Y-m-d');

        return AnnotationsModel::with('informationPanel', 'annotationType', 'annotationState', 'follows', 'resident')
        ->where('centerId', $AnnotationsData['id'])->whereIn('informationPanelId', $ids)->where('active', 1)->where( 'date', '>', $dateNowSubXDays )->orderBy('date', 'desc')
        ->orderBy('hour', 'desc')->orderBy('minutes', 'desc')->get();
```

He probado deshabilitando el QueryLog pero no consigo hacerlo. Siempre me da error. He mirando el comando `chunck`, pero me da la impresión que es para tratar una cantidad elevada de datos pero yo solo quiero traérmelos no trabajar con esos datos.
 También he probado aumentando el `memory_limit` del `php.ini` y funciona bien, pero no quiero aumentar el limite solo para una sola consulta.

Answer (score 0):

Lo que podrias hacer es actualizar el limite de **php.ini** algo así:

```
memory_limit=1024M
```

despues de esto reinicia tu apache y listo.. prueba con ello y me avisas.

Comment: Perdona pero se me había olvidado comentar que esto lo he probado y si funciona. Pero no quisiera tener que aumentar el limite de memoria solo por una consulta. Edito mi pregunta para añadir esto. Muchas gracias.